# Pascal's Triangle with iterative algorithm via list comprehension in Python

Tags: python

Just for the sake of exercise I'm trying to find a way to express [Pascal's Triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) with Python list comprehension, and do that **in iterative way**. I'm representing Pascal's Triangle in Python as:

```
tri = [[1], [1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 3, 1], [1, 4, 6, 4, 1], ...]
```

As I'm doing it iteratively, I need to somehow access previously calculated lines of the triangle, and I'm trying to do this *without declaring a local variable*.

So far I have this:

```
tri = [lines.append(
    ([1] + [lines[i][j]+lines[i][j-1] for j in xrange(1, i+1)] + [1]) if i > 0 
        else [1, 1]) 
    or lines[i] for i, lines in enumerate([[[1]]]*height)]
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: As pointed out by @brc this is really bad example of how and/or when to use list comprehensions.

Comment: In case anyone else gets any ideas, this is a great example of when *not* to use list comprehensions.  As an exercise, fine, but don't ever use something like that in real code, please.

Comment: What?  Aren't `i` and `lines` and `j` local variables???

Comment: @brc Totally, I probably should've put that note in my question.

Comment: @MattFenwick Yes, but they are declared implicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obeying all the slightly insane restrictions you imposed upon yourself, the only simplifications I can think of are incorporated here:

```
[d.setdefault(j, [sum(d[len(d)-1][max(i, 0):i + 2]) for i in range(-1, j)])
 for j, d in enumerate([{0: [1]}] * 5)]
```

At least this is shorter than your version and gets rid of all the conditional expressions.  Of course it's still insane.

Comment: I like this answer, although this (sadly) works a bit slower than my initial ugly version.

Answer (score 9):

You can simply use the definition of the [binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient):

```
from math import factorial
tri = [[factorial(n) // (factorial(k) * factorial(n - k)) for k in range(n+1)]
  for n in range(height)]
```

Comment: +1 for using math (I wish it could be +10 for a problem like this)

Answer (score 1):

As explicitly iterative approaches are wanted, I would use an iterator.

```
def bincoeff(num=None):
    from math import factorial
    if num is None:
        it = iter(lambda: True, False) # waiting for Godot
    else:
        it = xrange(num)
    for _ in it:
        yield [factorial(n) // (factorial(k) * factorial(n - k)) for k in range(n+1)]
```

With this generator, you can

- build a list:

  ```
  bc = list(bincoeff(100))
  ```
- get all up to a certain maximum:

  ```
  for bc in bincoeff():
      if len(bc) > 100: break
      print bc
  ```
- ...